# Making Text fit to HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to render some text to a seperate canvas like so:

```
var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var tmpContext = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
tmpContext.textAlign = 'center';
tmpContext.font = size + 'px';
tmpCanvas.width = tmpContext.measureText(txt).width;
tmpCanvas.height = size;
tmpContext.fillStyle = "#000";
tmpContext.fillRect(0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height);
tmpContext.fillStyle = color;
tmpContext.fillText(txt, tmpCanvas.width / 2, tmpCanvas.height / 2);
```

This canvas is then rendered to the main canvas' centre:

```
context.drawImage(cachedText, (d_canvas.width / 2) - (cachedText.width / 2), (d_canvas.height / 2) - (cachedText.width / 2), cachedText.width, cachedText.height);
```

I am doing this, because the text that is drawn is quite complex so I do not want to repeat the drawing operation several times. However, the issue is that despite the fact that I have set the canvas size to be equal to the text size, the text is smaller than the canvas, and it is off center. How can I create a canvas/image object with a pre rendered text on it as I have attempted above.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/x4t1vjam/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, there was a few problems with your code. First and foremost, when you set a font size on a canvas, you must also set a font type - in my example, it is set as a generic 'serif' font.

Secondly, your drawing code is in a weird order, so after the font size was being used to set the width of the canvas, it was being overridden before it could be used to draw the font.

Lastly, the positioning logic is wrong. I've tried the best I can quickly to fix it, but it'll need some tweaking. You can see it **mostly** working here;

http://jsfiddle.net/x4t1vjam/5/

The code will need cleaned up, possibly storing some of the values in variables earlier in the code to avoid declaring them twice. And because I can't post an answer without a code sample, here's where I've made my changes.

```
  tmpContext.textAlign = 'center';
  tmpContext.font = size + "px serif";
  tmpCanvas.width = tmpContext.measureText(txt).width;
  tmpCanvas.height = size;
  tmpContext.fillStyle = "#000";
  tmpContext.fillRect(0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height);
  tmpContext.fillStyle = color;
  tmpContext.font = "100px serif";
  tmpContext.fillText(txt, (tmpCanvas.width / 2) - tmpContext.measureText(txt).width / 2,
                      size);
```

Comment: When I change the size to 200, it looks really bad. The height of the canvas seems to be changing, but the text remains the same.

Comment: Because you are setting the height to be the size, here `tmpCanvas.height = size` - Turns out there are a few mistakes here. Let me go through the others and update my answer.

Comment: yeah, but the text should scale up to that size as well, because I set the font size to that. right?

Comment: Oh I messed up. Thank you! I wasnt aware that setting the fillstyle resets the .font attribute.

Comment: Neither was I. It seems a strange way for the canvas to handle things.